# Watch a variable (memory address) change in Linux kernel, and print stack trace when it changes?

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel

I would like to somehow "watch" a variable (or a memory address, rather) in the Linux kernel (a kernel module/driver, to be exact); and find out what changed it - basically, print out a stack trace when the variable changed.

For instance, in the kernel module `testjiffy-hr.c` listed at end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920238/reliability-of-linux-kernel-add-timer-at-resolution-of-one-jiffy/17055867#17055867), I would like to print out a stack trace each time the `runcount` variable changes; hopefully the stack trace then would contain a mention of `testjiffy_timer_function`, which is indeed the function that changes that variable.

Now, I know I can use `kgdb` to connect to a debug Linux kernel running in say a virtual machine, and even set breakpoints (so hopefully, also watchpoints) like that - but the problem is that I actually want to debug an ALSA driver, in particular the playback `dma_area` buffer (where I'm getting some unexpected data) - which is highly sensitive to timing; and running the debug kernel in itself would mess up the timings (let alone running it in a virtual machine).

An even bigger problem here is that the playback `dma_area` pointer exists only during a playback operation (or in other words, between the `_start` and `_stop` handlers) - so I'd have to record the `dma_area` address at each `_start` callback, and then somehow "schedule" it for "watching" during the playback operation.

So I was hoping there was a way to do something like this directly in the driver code - as in, add some code in this `_start` callback which records the `dma_area` pointer, and use it as an argument to a command which initiates the "watch" for a change; with the stack trace printed from a corresponding callback function. (I'm aware that this too would influence the timing, but I was hoping it would be "light" enough not to influence the "live" driver operation too much).

So my question is: does such a technique for debugging in the Linux kernel exist?

If not: is it possible to set up a hardware (or software) interrupt, that reacts on a change of a specific memory address? Then could I set up such an interrupt handler, that could print out a stack trace? (although, I think the whole context changes when IRQ handlers run, so maybe getting a stack trace there would be wrong)?

If not: are there any other techniques left, that would allow me to print a stack trace of the process that changed the value stored in a given memory location in the kernel ( hopefully in a live, non-debug kernel)?

Comment: If your hardware supports hardware breakpoints, they might be what you need. Here is [an example](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/samples/hw_breakpoint/). See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362063/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Many thanks for the replies by [@CosminRatiu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19734787/277826) and [Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19725900/watch-a-variable-memory-address-change-in-linux-kernel-and-print-stack-trace#comment29352526_19734787); thanks to those, I found:

- [debugging - Linux kernel hardware break points - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362063/linux-kernel-hardware-break-points/16377522#16377522)
- [Hardware Breakpoint (or watchpoint) - The Linux Kernel Archives](https://www.kernel.org/doc/ols/2009/ols2009-pages-149-158.pdf)

... with which I could develop the example I'm posting here, the `testhrarr.c` kernel module/driver and the `Makefile` (below). It demonstrates that the hardware watchpoint tracing can be achieved in two ways: either using the `perf` program, which can probe the driver unchanged; or by adding some hardware breakpoint code to the driver (in the example, enveloped by the `HWDEBUG_STACK` define variable).

Essentially, debugging contents of standard atomic variable types like ints (like the `runcount` variable) are straightforward, as long as they are defined as a global variable in the kernel module, so they end up showing as a kernel symbol globally. Because of that, the code below adds the `testhrarr_` as prefix to the variables (so as to avoid naming conflicts). However, debugging contents of arrays may be a bit trickier, due to the need for dereferencing - so that is what this post demonstrates, debug of the first byte of the `testhrarr_arr` array. It was done on:

```
$ echo `cat /etc/lsb-release` 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_RELEASE=11.04 DISTRIB_CODENAME=natty DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 11.04"
$ uname -a
Linux mypc 2.6.38-16-generic #67-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 6 18:00:43 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name"
model name  : Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N450   @ 1.66GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N450   @ 1.66GHz
```

The `testhrarr` module basically allocates memory for a small array upon module initialization, sets up a timer function, and exposes a `/proc/testhrarr_proc` file (using the newer `proc_create` interface). Then, attempting to read from the `/proc/testhrarr_proc` file (say, using `cat`) will trigger the timer function, which will modify the `testhrarr_arr` array values, and dump messages to `/var/log/syslog`. We expect that `testhrarr_arr[0]` will change three times during the operation; once in `testhrarr_startup`, and twice in `testhrarr_timer_function` (due to wrapping).

### using `perf`

After building the module with `make`, you can load it with:

```
sudo insmod ./testhrarr.ko
```

At that point, `/var/log/syslog` would contain:

```
kernel: [40277.199913] Init testhrarr: 0 ; HZ: 250 ; 1/HZ (ms): 4 ; hrres: 0.000000001
kernel: [40277.199930]  Addresses: _runcount 0xf84be22c ; _arr 0xf84be2a0 ; _arr[0] 0xed182a80 (0xed182a80) ; _timer_function 0xf84bc1c3 ; my_hrtimer 0xf84be260; my_hrt.f 0xf84be27c
kernel: [40277.220329] HW Breakpoint for testhrarr_arr write installed (0xf84be2a0)
```

Note that just passing `testhrarr_arr` as symbol for hardware watchpoint scans the address of that variable (`0xf84be2a0`), not the address of the first element of the array (`0xed182a80`)! Because of this, the hardware breakpoint is *not* going to trigger - so the behavior will be as if the hardware breakpoint code is not present at all (which can be achieved by undefining `HWDEBUG_STACK`)!

So, even without a hardware breakpoint set through kernel module code, we can still use `perf` to observe a change of a memory address - in `perf`, we specify both the address we want to watch (here the address of the first element of `testhrarr_arr`, `0xed182a80`), and the process which should be ran: here we run `bash`, so we can execute a `cat /proc/testhrarr_proc` which will trigger the kernel module timer, followed by a `sleep 0.5` which will allow the timer to complete. The `-a` parameter is also needed, otherwise some events may be missed:

```
$ sudo perf record -a --call-graph --event=mem:0xed182a80:w bash -c 'cat /proc/testhrarr_proc ; sleep 0.5'
testhrarr proc: startup
[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.485 MB perf.data (~21172 samples) ]
```

At this point, `/var/log/syslog` would also contain something like:

```
[40822.114964]  testhrarr_timer_function: testhrarr_runcount 0 
[40822.114980]  testhrarr jiffies 10130528 ; ret: 1 ; ktnsec: 40822114975062
[40822.118956]  testhrarr_timer_function: testhrarr_runcount 1 
[40822.118977]  testhrarr jiffies 10130529 ; ret: 1 ; ktnsec: 40822118973195
[40822.122940]  testhrarr_timer_function: testhrarr_runcount 2 
[40822.122956]  testhrarr jiffies 10130530 ; ret: 1 ; ktnsec: 40822122951143
[40822.126962]  testhrarr_timer_function: testhrarr_runcount 3 
[40822.126978]  testhrarr jiffies 10130531 ; ret: 1 ; ktnsec: 40822126973583
[40822.130941]  testhrarr_timer_function: testhrarr_runcount 4 
[40822.130961]  testhrarr jiffies 10130532 ; ret: 1 ; ktnsec: 40822130955167
[40822.134940]  testhrarr_timer_function: testhrarr_runcount 5 
[40822.134962]  testhrarr jiffies 10130533 ; ret: 1 ; ktnsec: 40822134958888
[40822.138936]  testhrarr_timer_function: testhrarr_runcount 6 
[40822.138958]  testhrarr jiffies 10130534 ; ret: 1 ; ktnsec: 40822138955693
[40822.142940]  testhrarr_timer_function: testhrarr_runcount 7 
[40822.142962]  testhrarr jiffies 10130535 ; ret: 1 ; ktnsec: 40822142959345
[40822.146936]  testhrarr_timer_function: testhrarr_runcount 8 
[40822.146957]  testhrarr jiffies 10130536 ; ret: 1 ; ktnsec: 40822146954479
[40822.150949]  testhrarr_timer_function: testhrarr_runcount 9 
[40822.150970]  testhrarr jiffies 10130537 ; ret: 1 ; ktnsec: 40822150963438
[40822.154974]  testhrarr_timer_function: testhrarr_runcount 10 
[40822.154988] testhrarr [ 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, ]
```

To read the capture of `perf` (a file called `perf.data`) we can use:

```
$ sudo perf report --call-graph flat --stdio
No kallsyms or vmlinux with build-id 5031df4d8668bcc45a7bdb4023909c6f8e2d3d34 was found
[testhrarr] with build id 5031df4d8668bcc45a7bdb4023909c6f8e2d3d34 not found, continuing without symbols
Failed to open /bin/cat, continuing without symbols
Failed to open /usr/lib/libpixman-1.so.0.20.2, continuing without symbols
Failed to open /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so, continuing without symbols
Failed to open /usr/bin/Xorg, continuing without symbols
# Events: 5  unknown
#
# Overhead  Command  Shared Object                                Symbol
# ........  .......  .............  ....................................
#
    87.50%     Xorg  [testhrarr]    [k] testhrarr_timer_function
            87.50%
                testhrarr_timer_function
                __run_hrtimer
                hrtimer_interrupt
                smp_apic_timer_interrupt
                apic_timer_interrupt
                0x30185d
                0x2ed701
                0x2ed8cc
                0x2edba0
                0x9d0386
                0x8126fc8
                0x81217a1
                0x811bdd3
                0x8070aa7
                0x806281c
                __libc_start_main
                0x8062411

     6.25%      cat  [testhrarr]    [k] testhrarr_timer_function
             6.25%
                testhrarr_timer_function
                testhrarr_proc_show
                seq_read
                proc_reg_read
                vfs_read
                sys_read
                syscall_call
                0xaa2416
                0x8049f4d
                __libc_start_main
                0x8049081

     3.12%  swapper  [testhrarr]    [k] testhrarr_timer_function
             3.12%
                testhrarr_timer_function
                __run_hrtimer
                hrtimer_interrupt
                smp_apic_timer_interrupt
                apic_timer_interrupt
                cpuidle_idle_call
                cpu_idle
                start_secondary

     3.12%      cat  [testhrarr]    [k] 0x356   
             3.12%
                0xf84bc356
                0xf84bc3a7
                seq_read
                proc_reg_read
                vfs_read
                sys_read
                syscall_call
                0xaa2416
                0x8049f4d
                __libc_start_main
                0x8049081



#
# (For a higher level overview, try: perf report --sort comm,dso)
#
```

So, since we're building the kernel module with debugging on (`-g` in the `Makefile`), it is not a problem for `perf` to find this module's symbols, even if the live kernel is not a debug kernel. So it correctly interprets `testhrarr_timer_function` as the setter most of the time, although it doesn't report `testhrarr_startup` (but it does report `testhrarr_proc_show` which calls it). There are also references to `0xf84bc3a7` and `0xf84bc356` which it couldn't resolve; however, note that the module is loaded at `0xf84bc000`:

```
$ sudo cat /proc/modules | grep testhr
testhrarr 13433 0 - Live 0xf84bc000
```

... and that entry also starts with `...[k] 0x356`; and if we look in the `objdump` of the kernel module:

```
$ objdump -S testhrarr.ko | less
...
00000323 :

static void testhrarr_startup(void)
{
...
    testhrarr_arr[0] = 0; //just the first element
 34b:   a1 80 00 00 00          mov    0x80,%eax
 350:   c7 00 00 00 00 00       movl   $0x0,(%eax)
    hrtimer_start(&my_hrtimer, ktime_period_ns, HRTIMER_MODE_REL);
 356:   c7 04 24 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,(%esp)                     **********
 35d:   8b 15 1c 00 00 00       mov    0x1c,%edx
...
00000375 :


static int testhrarr_proc_show(struct seq_file *m, void *v) {
...
    seq_printf(m, "testhrarr proc: startup\n");
 38f:   c7 44 24 04 79 00 00    movl   $0x79,0x4(%esp)
 396:   00 
 397:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
 39a:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 39d:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   39e 
    testhrarr_startup();
 3a2:   e8 7c ff ff ff          call   323 
 3a7:   eb 1c                   jmp    3c5   **********
  } else {
    seq_printf(m, "testhrarr proc: (is running, %d)\n", testhrarr_runcount);
 3a9:   a1 0c 00 00 00          mov    0xc,%eax
...
```

... so `0xf84bc356` apparently refers to `hrtimer_start`; and `0xf84bc3a7` -> `3a7` refers to its calling `testhrarr_proc_show` function; which thankfully makes sense. (Note that I've experienced with different versions of the driver, that the `_start` could show, and the `timer_function` to be expressed by sheer addresses; not sure what this is due).

One problem with `perf`, though, is that it gives me a statistical "Overhead" of these functions occurring (not sure what that refers to - probably time spent between entry and exit of a function?) - but what I want, really, is a log of stack traces which is sequential. Not sure if `perf` can be set up for that - but it definitely be done with kernel module code for hardware breakpoints.

### using kernel module HW breakpoint

The code which is in the `HWDEBUG_STACK` implements the HW breakpoint setup and handling. As noted, the default set up for the symbol `ksym_name` (if unspecified), is `testhrarr_arr`, which doesn't trigger the hardware breakpoint at all. The `ksym_name` parameter can be specified on the command line during `insmod`; here we can note that:

```
$ sudo rmmod testhrarr    # remove module if still loaded
$ sudo insmod ./testhrarr.ko ksym=testhrarr_arr[0]
```

... results with a `HW Breakpoint for testhrarr_arr[0] write installed (0x  (null))` in `/var/log/syslog`; - which means we cannot use symbols with bracket notation for array access; thankfully a null pointer here simply means that HW breakpoint will again not fire; it doesn't crash the OS completely `:)`

There is, however, a global variable made to refer to the first element of the `testhrarr_arr` array, called `testhrarr_arr_first` - note how this global variable is specially handled in the code, and needs to be dereferenced, so that the correct address is obtained. So we do:

```
$ sudo rmmod testhrarr    # remove module if still loaded
$ sudo insmod ./testhrarr.ko ksym=testhrarr_arr_first
```

... and the syslog informs:

```
kernel: [43910.509726] Init testhrarr: 0 ; HZ: 250 ; 1/HZ (ms): 4 ; hrres: 0.000000001
kernel: [43910.509765]  Addresses: _runcount 0xf84be22c ; _arr 0xf84be2a0 ; _arr[0] 0xedf6c5c0 (0xedf6c5c0) ; _timer_function 0xf84bc1c3 ; my_hrtimer 0xf84be260; my_hrt.f 0xf84be27c
kernel: [43910.538535] HW Breakpoint for testhrarr_arr_first write installed (0xedf6c5c0)
```

... and we can see that the HW breakpoint is set at `0xedf6c5c0`, which is the address of `testhrarr_arr[0]`. Now if we trigger the driver via the `/proc` file:

```
$ cat /proc/testhrarr_proc 
testhrarr proc: startup
```

... we obtain in `syslog`:

```
kernel: [44069.735695] testhrarr_arr_first value is changed
[44069.735711] Pid: 29320, comm: cat Not tainted 2.6.38-16-generic #67-Ubuntu
[44069.735719] Call Trace:
[44069.735737]  [] ? sample_hbp_handler+0x2d/0x3b [testhrarr]
[44069.735755]  [] ? __perf_event_overflow+0x90/0x240
[44069.735768]  [] ? proc_alloc_inode+0x23/0x90
[44069.735778]  [] ? proc_alloc_inode+0x23/0x90
[44069.735790]  [] ? perf_swevent_event+0x136/0x140
[44069.735801]  [] ? perf_bp_event+0x70/0x80
[44069.735812]  [] ? prep_new_page+0x110/0x1a0
[44069.735824]  [] ? get_page_from_freelist+0x12e/0x320
[44069.735836]  [] ? seq_open+0x3d/0xa0
[44069.735848]  [] ? hw_breakpoint_handler.clone.0+0x102/0x130
[44069.735861]  [] ? hw_breakpoint_exceptions_notify+0x22/0x30
[44069.735872]  [] ? notifier_call_chain+0x45/0x60
[44069.735883]  [] ? atomic_notifier_call_chain+0x22/0x30
[44069.735894]  [] ? notify_die+0x2d/0x30
[44069.735904]  [] ? do_debug+0x88/0x180
[44069.735915]  [] ? debug_stack_correct+0x30/0x38
[44069.735928]  [] ? testhrarr_startup+0x33/0x52 [testhrarr]
[44069.735940]  [] ? testhrarr_proc_show+0x32/0x57 [testhrarr]
[44069.735952]  [] ? seq_read+0x145/0x390
[44069.735963]  [] ? seq_read+0x0/0x390
[44069.735973]  [] ? proc_reg_read+0x64/0xa0
[44069.735985]  [] ? vfs_read+0x9f/0x160
[44069.735995]  [] ? proc_reg_read+0x0/0xa0
[44069.736003]  [] ? sys_read+0x42/0x70
[44069.736013]  [] ? syscall_call+0x7/0xb
[44069.736019] Dump stack from sample_hbp_handler
[44069.740132]  testhrarr_timer_function: testhrarr_runcount 0 
[44069.740146]  testhrarr jiffies 10942435 ; ret: 1 ; ktnsec: 44069740142485
[44069.740159] testhrarr_arr_first value is changed
[44069.740169] Pid: 4302, comm: gnome-terminal Not tainted 2.6.38-16-generic #67-Ubuntu
[44069.740176] Call Trace:
[44069.740195]  [] ? sample_hbp_handler+0x2d/0x3b [testhrarr]
[44069.740213]  [] ? __perf_event_overflow+0x90/0x240
[44069.740227]  [] ? perf_swevent_event+0x136/0x140
[44069.740239]  [] ? perf_bp_event+0x70/0x80
[44069.740253]  [] ? sched_clock_local+0xd3/0x1c0
[44069.740267]  [] ? format_decode+0x323/0x380
[44069.740280]  [] ? hw_breakpoint_handler.clone.0+0x102/0x130
[44069.740292]  [] ? hw_breakpoint_exceptions_notify+0x22/0x30
[44069.740302]  [] ? notifier_call_chain+0x45/0x60
[44069.740313]  [] ? atomic_notifier_call_chain+0x22/0x30
[44069.740324]  [] ? notify_die+0x2d/0x30
[44069.740335]  [] ? do_debug+0x88/0x180
[44069.740345]  [] ? debug_stack_correct+0x30/0x38
[44069.740364]  [] ? init_intel_cacheinfo+0x103/0x394
[44069.740379]  [] ? testhrarr_timer_function+0xed/0x160 [testhrarr]
[44069.740391]  [] ? __run_hrtimer+0x6f/0x190
[44069.740404]  [] ? testhrarr_timer_function+0x0/0x160 [testhrarr]
[44069.740416]  [] ? hrtimer_interrupt+0x108/0x240
[44069.740430]  [] ? smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x56/0x8a
[44069.740441]  [] ? apic_timer_interrupt+0x31/0x38
[44069.740453]  [] ? _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x15/0x20
[44069.740465]  [] ? try_to_del_timer_sync+0x67/0xb0
[44069.740476]  [] ? del_timer_sync+0x29/0x50
[44069.740486]  [] ? flush_delayed_work+0x13/0x40
[44069.740500]  [] ? tty_flush_to_ldisc+0x12/0x20
[44069.740510]  [] ? n_tty_poll+0x4f/0x190
[44069.740523]  [] ? tty_poll+0x6d/0x90
[44069.740531]  [] ? n_tty_poll+0x0/0x190
[44069.740542]  [] ? do_poll.clone.3+0xd0/0x210
[44069.740553]  [] ? do_sys_poll+0x134/0x1e0
[44069.740563]  [] ? __pollwait+0x0/0xd0
[44069.740572]  [] ? pollwake+0x0/0x60
...
[44069.740742]  [] ? pollwake+0x0/0x60
[44069.740757]  [] ? rw_verify_area+0x6c/0x130
[44069.740770]  [] ? ktime_get_ts+0xf8/0x120
[44069.740781]  [] ? poll_select_set_timeout+0x64/0x70
[44069.740793]  [] ? sys_poll+0x5a/0xd0
[44069.740804]  [] ? syscall_call+0x7/0xb
[44069.740815]  [] ? init_intel_cacheinfo+0x23/0x394
[44069.740822] Dump stack from sample_hbp_handler
[44069.744130]  testhrarr_timer_function: testhrarr_runcount 1 
[44069.744143]  testhrarr jiffies 10942436 ; ret: 1 ; ktnsec: 44069744140055
[44069.748132]  testhrarr_timer_function: testhrarr_runcount 2 
[44069.748145]  testhrarr jiffies 10942437 ; ret: 1 ; ktnsec: 44069748141271
[44069.752131]  testhrarr_timer_function: testhrarr_runcount 3 
[44069.752145]  testhrarr jiffies 10942438 ; ret: 1 ; ktnsec: 44069752141164
[44069.756131]  testhrarr_timer_function: testhrarr_runcount 4 
[44069.756141]  testhrarr jiffies 10942439 ; ret: 1 ; ktnsec: 44069756138318
[44069.760130]  testhrarr_timer_function: testhrarr_runcount 5 
[44069.760141]  testhrarr jiffies 10942440 ; ret: 1 ; ktnsec: 44069760138469
[44069.760154] testhrarr_arr_first value is changed
[44069.760164] Pid: 4302, comm: gnome-terminal Not tainted 2.6.38-16-generic #67-Ubuntu
[44069.760170] Call Trace:
[44069.760187]  [] ? sample_hbp_handler+0x2d/0x3b [testhrarr]
[44069.760202]  [] ? __perf_event_overflow+0x90/0x240
[44069.760213]  [] ? perf_swevent_event+0x136/0x140
[44069.760224]  [] ? perf_bp_event+0x70/0x80
[44069.760235]  [] ? sched_clock_local+0xd3/0x1c0
[44069.760247]  [] ? format_decode+0x323/0x380
[44069.760258]  [] ? hw_breakpoint_handler.clone.0+0x102/0x130
[44069.760269]  [] ? hw_breakpoint_exceptions_notify+0x22/0x30
[44069.760279]  [] ? notifier_call_chain+0x45/0x60
[44069.760289]  [] ? atomic_notifier_call_chain+0x22/0x30
[44069.760299]  [] ? notify_die+0x2d/0x30
[44069.760308]  [] ? do_debug+0x88/0x180
[44069.760318]  [] ? debug_stack_correct+0x30/0x38
[44069.760334]  [] ? init_intel_cacheinfo+0x103/0x394
[44069.760345]  [] ? testhrarr_timer_function+0xed/0x160 [testhrarr]
[44069.760356]  [] ? __run_hrtimer+0x6f/0x190
[44069.760366]  [] ? send_to_group.clone.1+0xf8/0x150
[44069.760376]  [] ? testhrarr_timer_function+0x0/0x160 [testhrarr]
[44069.760387]  [] ? hrtimer_interrupt+0x108/0x240
[44069.760396]  [] ? fsnotify+0x1a5/0x290
[44069.760407]  [] ? smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x56/0x8a
[44069.760416]  [] ? apic_timer_interrupt+0x31/0x38
[44069.760428]  [] ? mem_cgroup_resize_limit+0x108/0x1c0
[44069.760437]  [] ? fput+0x0/0x30
[44069.760446]  [] ? sys_write+0x67/0x70
[44069.760455]  [] ? syscall_call+0x7/0xb
[44069.760464]  [] ? init_intel_cacheinfo+0x23/0x394
[44069.760470] Dump stack from sample_hbp_handler
[44069.764134]  testhrarr_timer_function: testhrarr_runcount 6 
[44069.764147]  testhrarr jiffies 10942441 ; ret: 1 ; ktnsec: 44069764144141
[44069.768133]  testhrarr_timer_function: testhrarr_runcount 7 
[44069.768146]  testhrarr jiffies 10942442 ; ret: 1 ; ktnsec: 44069768142976
[44069.772134]  testhrarr_timer_function: testhrarr_runcount 8 
[44069.772148]  testhrarr jiffies 10942443 ; ret: 1 ; ktnsec: 44069772144121
[44069.776132]  testhrarr_timer_function: testhrarr_runcount 9 
[44069.776145]  testhrarr jiffies 10942444 ; ret: 1 ; ktnsec: 44069776141971
[44069.780133]  testhrarr_timer_function: testhrarr_runcount 10 
[44069.780141] testhrarr [ 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, ]
```

... we get a stack trace exactly three times - once during `testhrarr_startup`, and twice in `testhrarr_timer_function`: once for `runcount==0` and once for `runcount==5`, as expected.

Well, hope this helps someone,
Cheers!

---

**`Makefile`**

```
CONFIG_MODULE_FORCE_UNLOAD=y

# debug build:
# "CFLAGS was changed ... Fix it to use EXTRA_CFLAGS."
override EXTRA_CFLAGS+=-g -O0 

obj-m += testhrarr.o
#testhrarr-objs  := testhrarr.o

all:
    @echo EXTRA_CFLAGS = $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

**`testhrarr.c`**

```
/*
 * [http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html#AEN189 The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide]
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920238/reliability-of-linux-kernel-add-timer-at-resolution-of-one-jiffy/17055867#17055867
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516021/proc-create-example-for-kernel-module/18924359#18924359
 * http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/samples/hw_breakpoint/data_breakpoint.c
 */


#include <linux/module.h>   /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>   /* Needed for KERN_INFO */
#include <linux/init.h>     /* Needed for the macros */
#include <linux/jiffies.h>
#include <linux/time.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>  /* /proc entry */
#include <linux/seq_file.h> /* /proc entry */
#define ARRSIZE 5
#define MAXRUNS 2*ARRSIZE

#include <linux/hrtimer.h>

#define HWDEBUG_STACK 1

#if (HWDEBUG_STACK == 1)
#include <linux/perf_event.h>
#include <linux/hw_breakpoint.h>

struct perf_event * __percpu *sample_hbp;
static char ksym_name[KSYM_NAME_LEN] = "testhrarr_arr";
module_param_string(ksym, ksym_name, KSYM_NAME_LEN, S_IRUGO);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(ksym, "Kernel symbol to monitor; this module will report any"
      " write operations on the kernel symbol");
#endif

static volatile int testhrarr_runcount = 0;
static volatile int testhrarr_isRunning = 0;

static unsigned long period_ms;
static unsigned long period_ns;
static ktime_t ktime_period_ns;
static struct hrtimer my_hrtimer;

static int* testhrarr_arr;
static int* testhrarr_arr_first;

static enum hrtimer_restart testhrarr_timer_function(struct hrtimer *timer)
{
  unsigned long tjnow;
  ktime_t kt_now;
  int ret_overrun;

  printk(KERN_INFO
    " %s: testhrarr_runcount %d \n",
    __func__, testhrarr_runcount);

  if (testhrarr_runcount < MAXRUNS) {
    tjnow = jiffies;
    kt_now = hrtimer_cb_get_time(&my_hrtimer);
    ret_overrun = hrtimer_forward(&my_hrtimer, kt_now, ktime_period_ns);
    printk(KERN_INFO
      " testhrarr jiffies %lu ; ret: %d ; ktnsec: %lld\n",
      tjnow, ret_overrun, ktime_to_ns(kt_now));
    testhrarr_arr[(testhrarr_runcount % ARRSIZE)] += testhrarr_runcount;
    testhrarr_runcount++;
    return HRTIMER_RESTART;
  }
  else {
    int i;
    testhrarr_isRunning = 0;
    // do not use KERN_DEBUG etc, if printk buffering until newline is desired!
    printk("testhrarr_arr [ ");
    for(i=0; i<ARRSIZE; i++) {
      printk("%d, ", testhrarr_arr[i]);
    }
    printk("]\n");
    return HRTIMER_NORESTART;
  }
}

static void testhrarr_startup(void)
{
  if (testhrarr_isRunning == 0) {
    testhrarr_isRunning = 1;
    testhrarr_runcount = 0;
    testhrarr_arr[0] = 0; //just the first element
    hrtimer_start(&my_hrtimer, ktime_period_ns, HRTIMER_MODE_REL);
  }
}


static int testhrarr_proc_show(struct seq_file *m, void *v) {
  if (testhrarr_isRunning == 0) {
    seq_printf(m, "testhrarr proc: startup\n");
    testhrarr_startup();
  } else {
    seq_printf(m, "testhrarr proc: (is running, %d)\n", testhrarr_runcount);
  }
  return 0;
}

static int testhrarr_proc_open(struct inode *inode, struct  file *file) {
  return single_open(file, testhrarr_proc_show, NULL);
}

static const struct file_operations testhrarr_proc_fops = {
  .owner = THIS_MODULE,
  .open = testhrarr_proc_open,
  .read = seq_read,
  .llseek = seq_lseek,
  .release = single_release,
};


#if (HWDEBUG_STACK == 1)
static void sample_hbp_handler(struct perf_event *bp,
             struct perf_sample_data *data,
             struct pt_regs *regs)
{
  printk(KERN_INFO "%s value is changed\n", ksym_name);
  dump_stack();
  printk(KERN_INFO "Dump stack from sample_hbp_handler\n");
}
#endif

static int __init testhrarr_init(void)
{
  struct timespec tp_hr_res;
  #if (HWDEBUG_STACK == 1)
  struct perf_event_attr attr;
  #endif

  period_ms = 1000/HZ;
  hrtimer_get_res(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tp_hr_res);
  printk(KERN_INFO
    "Init testhrarr: %d ; HZ: %d ; 1/HZ (ms): %ld ; hrres: %lld.%.9ld\n",
               testhrarr_runcount,      HZ,        period_ms, (long long)tp_hr_res.tv_sec, tp_hr_res.tv_nsec );

  testhrarr_arr = (int*)kcalloc(ARRSIZE, sizeof(int), GFP_ATOMIC);
  testhrarr_arr_first = &testhrarr_arr[0];

  hrtimer_init(&my_hrtimer, CLOCK_MONOTONIC, HRTIMER_MODE_REL);
  my_hrtimer.function = &testhrarr_timer_function;
  period_ns = period_ms*( (unsigned long)1E6L );
  ktime_period_ns = ktime_set(0,period_ns);

  printk(KERN_INFO
    " Addresses: _runcount 0x%p ; _arr 0x%p ; _arr[0] 0x%p (0x%p) ; _timer_function 0x%p ; my_hrtimer 0x%p; my_hrt.f 0x%p\n",
    &testhrarr_runcount, &testhrarr_arr, &(testhrarr_arr[0]), testhrarr_arr_first, &testhrarr_timer_function, &my_hrtimer, &my_hrtimer.function);


  proc_create("testhrarr_proc", 0, NULL, &testhrarr_proc_fops);


  #if (HWDEBUG_STACK == 1)
  hw_breakpoint_init(&attr);
  if (strcmp(ksym_name, "testhrarr_arr_first") == 0) {
    // just for testhrarr_arr_first - interpret the found symbol address
    // as int*, and dereference it to get the "real" address it points to
    attr.bp_addr = *((int*)kallsyms_lookup_name(ksym_name));
  } else {
    // the usual - address is kallsyms_lookup_name result
    attr.bp_addr = kallsyms_lookup_name(ksym_name);
  }
  attr.bp_len = HW_BREAKPOINT_LEN_1;
  attr.bp_type = HW_BREAKPOINT_W ; //| HW_BREAKPOINT_R;

  sample_hbp = register_wide_hw_breakpoint(&attr, (perf_overflow_handler_t)sample_hbp_handler);
  if (IS_ERR((void __force *)sample_hbp)) {
    int ret = PTR_ERR((void __force *)sample_hbp);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Breakpoint registration failed\n");
    return ret;
  }

  // explicit cast needed to show 64-bit bp_addr as 32-bit address
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796909/how-to-resolve-cast-to-pointer-from-integer-of-different-size-warning-in-c-co/11797103#11797103
  printk(KERN_INFO "HW Breakpoint for %s write installed (0x%p)\n", ksym_name, (void*)(uintptr_t)attr.bp_addr);
  #endif

  return 0;
}

static void __exit testhrarr_exit(void)
{
  int ret_cancel = 0;
  kfree(testhrarr_arr);
  while( hrtimer_callback_running(&my_hrtimer) ) {
    ret_cancel++;
  }
  if (ret_cancel != 0) {
    printk(KERN_INFO " testhrarr Waited for hrtimer callback to finish (%d)\n", ret_cancel);
  }
  if (hrtimer_active(&my_hrtimer) != 0) {
    ret_cancel = hrtimer_cancel(&my_hrtimer);
    printk(KERN_INFO " testhrarr active hrtimer cancelled: %d (%d)\n", ret_cancel, testhrarr_runcount);
  }
  if (hrtimer_is_queued(&my_hrtimer) != 0) {
    ret_cancel = hrtimer_cancel(&my_hrtimer);
    printk(KERN_INFO " testhrarr queued hrtimer cancelled: %d (%d)\n", ret_cancel, testhrarr_runcount);
  }
  remove_proc_entry("testhrarr_proc", NULL);
  #if (HWDEBUG_STACK == 1)
  unregister_wide_hw_breakpoint(sample_hbp);
  printk(KERN_INFO "HW Breakpoint for %s write uninstalled\n", ksym_name);
  #endif
  printk(KERN_INFO "Exit testhrarr\n");
}

module_init(testhrarr_init);
module_exit(testhrarr_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: That is a *big* answer. Perhaps you should be writing a blog post on this subject, summarising the contents here in a shorter answer and linking to the blog for the full version?

Comment: Hi @Duncan, I see your point - but for one, I don't currently maintain a blog; another problem is that I've often seen complaints on SO when only a link is included. Here though, the problem is what should the summary be - for me, as a noob, it is important both to see some code _and_ the expected debug logs, so I included both, which is what takes up space - in hope that people won't mind, as at least the answer is self contained. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You need hardware support for this. The CPU need to sense when a certain memory address gets written to and call some code - an interrupt or exception handler. In my experience, I've seen this on the PowerPC platform but not on the x86. It's called a hardware watchpoint.

Theoretically, if you run in an emulator, you could simulate this behaviour, but I am completely unfamiliar with the currently existing emulators.

EDIT: I've dug a little more and it seems there is a general purpose hw breakpoint interface in Linux and that x86 has such a register. It's called DR7.
Look at function in 'include/linux/hw_breakpoint.h'. It looks like ptrace and/or perf use these interfaces. Good luck debugging it!

Comment: Many thanks @CosminRatiu - wasn't aware of the hardware watchpoint thing; good to know. An emulator, I guess, would still be too slow to meet the timings (just like a debug kernel inside a virtual machine is), so it wouldn't help my use case much. Accepted for now, as it looks like a generic technique for a live kernel code doesn't exist. Cheers!

Comment: x86 supports 4 hardware breakpoints that can be used to track memory accesses. In the kernel (version 3.2 or newer is recommended), one can set / clear them using API provided by Perf: [register_wide_hw_breakpoint()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=register_wide_hw_breakpoint), etc.

Comment: Many thanks for that @Eugene - found your other answer too, which helped me develop my answer; also CosminRatiu, moved the accept to my answer, as it contains an example. Thanks again, cheers!