# Find the access direction (read or write) for a Linux kernel hardware watch- or breakpoint?

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel

Consider the kernel module `testhrarr.c` given in [debugging - Watch a variable (memory address) change in Linux kernel, and print stack trace when it changes? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19725900/watch-a-variable-memory-address-change-in-linux-kernel-and-print-stack-trace/19755213#19755213), which tracks write accesses to a memory location.

Now, I'm trying to track read/write accesses, which I've done by changing this line in the `testhrarr_init` function:

```
attr.bp_type = HW_BREAKPOINT_W | HW_BREAKPOINT_R;
```

First subquestion here is this: on my platform (Linux kernel 2.6.38); `HW_BREAKPOINT_W` on its own works, and `HW_BREAKPOINT_W | HW_BREAKPOINT_R` for read/write works too - however trying only read access with `HW_BREAKPOINT_R` doesn't work; as I get "Breakpoint registration failed" in `/var/log/syslog`, and `insmod` fails with "insmod: error inserting './testhrarr.ko': -1 Invalid parameters". Does anyone have any idea why?

Anyways, the problem here is that once I'm watching for read/write access with `HW_BREAKPOINT_W | HW_BREAKPOINT_R`, I cannot tell in my handler whether the stack trace I'm getting is due to a read or a write access. I have gone through:

- struct `perf_event_attr` in [include/linux/perf_event.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/perf_event.h?v=2.6.38#L166)
- struct `hw_perf_event` [include/linux/perf_event.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/perf_event.h?v=2.6.38#L532)
- [include/linux/hw_breakpoint.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/hw_breakpoint.h?v=2.6.38) for the `HW_BREAKPOINT_*` enum definitions

... and I couldn't find anywhere an explicit technique to retrieve from the hw breakpoint handler, whether it was a read or write access that triggered. I only found something in [kernel/trace/trace_ksym.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/trace/trace_ksym.c?v=2.6.35), but `trace_ksym` has been deprecated (not even found in my 2.6.38), and besides it simply reads `attr.bp_type`, which is what we ourselves set in the kernel module.

So, after some brute-forcing, I realized that the `hw_perf_event->interrupts` may contain this information; so I modified the handler callback as:

```
static void sample_hbp_handler(struct perf_event *bp,
             struct perf_sample_data *data,
             struct pt_regs *regs)
{
  struct perf_event_attr attr = bp->attr;
  struct hw_perf_event   hw  = bp->hw;
  char hwirep[8];
  //it looks like printing %llu, data->type here causes segfault/oops when `cat` runs?
  // apparently, hw.interrupts changes depending on read/write access (1 or 2)
  // when only HW_BREAKPOINT_W, getting hw.interrupts == 1 always;
  // only HW_BREAKPOINT_R - fails for me
  // when both, hw.interrupts is either 1 or 2
  // defined in include/linux/hw_breakpoint.h:
  // HW_BREAKPOINT_R        = 1,  HW_BREAKPOINT_W       = 2,
  if (hw.interrupts == HW_BREAKPOINT_R) {
    strcpy(hwirep, "_R");
  } else if (hw.interrupts == HW_BREAKPOINT_W) {
    strcpy(hwirep, "_W");
  } else {
    strcpy(hwirep, "__");
  }
  printk(KERN_INFO "+--- %s value is accessed (.bp_type %d, .type %d, state %d htype %d hwi %llu / %s ) ---+\n", ksym_name, attr.bp_type, attr.type, hw.state, hw.info.type, hw.interrupts, hwirep);
  dump_stack();
  printk(KERN_INFO "|___ Dump stack from sample_hbp_handler ___|\n");
}
```

... and this seems to work somewhat; as I get the following in `syslog`:

```
$ grep "testhrarr_arr_first value" /var/log/syslog
kernel: [  200.887620] +--- testhrarr_arr_first value is accessed (.bp_type 3, .type 5, state 0 htype 131 hwi 1 / _R ) ---+
kernel: [  200.892163] +--- testhrarr_arr_first value is accessed (.bp_type 3, .type 5, state 0 htype 131 hwi 1 / _R ) ---+
kernel: [  200.892634] +--- testhrarr_arr_first value is accessed (.bp_type 3, .type 5, state 0 htype 131 hwi 2 / _W ) ---+
kernel: [  200.912192] +--- testhrarr_arr_first value is accessed (.bp_type 3, .type 5, state 0 htype 131 hwi 1 / _R ) ---+
kernel: [  200.912713] +--- testhrarr_arr_first value is accessed (.bp_type 3, .type 5, state 0 htype 131 hwi 2 / _W ) ---+
kernel: [  200.932138] +--- testhrarr_arr_first value is accessed (.bp_type 3, .type 5, state 0 htype 131 hwi 1 / _R ) ---+
```

... however, if `attr.bp_type` is just `HW_BREAKPOINT_W`, then just three `hw.interrupts == 1` are reported (which would be then wrongly reported as `_R` with the above code).

So then, if I just invert the meanings of `_R` and `_W`, I may get something that matches what I guess should occur - but this is quite obviously a shot in the dark, since I have no idea what `hw_perf_event->interrupts` should actually stand for.

So - does anyone know the proper way of determining the "direction" (read or write) of access to a hardware-watched memory location?

---

Edit: the answer for my first subquestion: for my architecture, x86, there is this piece of code:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/hw_breakpoint.c?v=2.6.38#L252

```
static int arch_build_bp_info(struct perf_event *bp)
{
  struct arch_hw_breakpoint *info = counter_arch_bp(bp);

  info->address = bp->attr.bp_addr;

  /* Type */
  switch (bp->attr.bp_type) {
  case HW_BREAKPOINT_W:
          info->type = X86_BREAKPOINT_WRITE;
          break;
  case HW_BREAKPOINT_W | HW_BREAKPOINT_R:
          info->type = X86_BREAKPOINT_RW;
          break;
  case HW_BREAKPOINT_X:
          info->type = X86_BREAKPOINT_EXECUTE;
          // ...
  default:
          return -EINVAL;
  }
...
}
```

... which clearly states that X86 has either `_WRITE` or `_RW` breakpoints; so if we try to set up just for `HW_BREAKPOINT_R`, the process would fail returning -EINVAL.

So, I guess, I'd need the answer here primarily for X86, although if there is a generic portable mechanism for determining read/write access, I'd rather know about that...